Excel VBA Code to Select ListBox Value acting very strange
I started this question several months ago, but it got closed down as I was working on other issues for a while.
I use code to pre-select values for several list boxes. Sometimes the code works and sometimes it does not work. When it does not work, the values on the ListBox are highlighted and it looks like it should work. However, the ListBox.value appears to freeze and remains null. The error most often occurs after saving a file. However, , if I go to the properties for a listbox and change multiselect to multi and then back to single, then other list boxes will fail too. That doesn't seem logical.
The following code works some times and sometimes it does not. It is random too. Sometimes attributeTable_Att2 works and attributeTable_Att3 doesn't work, or the other way around, or sometimes neither work.
Private Sub ComboBox_equipmentBaseline_Change()
If Me.ComboBox_equipmentBaseline.value <> "" Then
    '=====Populate the proposed equipment dropdown list based on selection in this baseline equipment dropdown=====
    'Me.Width = 602
    'Me.Height = 260
    ProjectState = "UT"
    'Me.ComboBox_equipmentProposed.List = getRetrofitProposedEquipmentListValues(ProjectState, Me.ComboBox_equipmentBaseline.Value)
    'Me.ComboBox_equipmentProposed.Value = ""
    'Me.ComboBox_equipmentProposed.SetFocus
    
    '=====Populate equipment attribute listboxes and textboxes based on selection in this dropdown=====
    Dim attributeTable_Att1 As String, attributeTable_Att2 As String, attributeTable_Att3 As String, attributeTable_Att4 As String
    attributeTable_Att1 = ""
    attributeTable_Att2 = ""
    attributeTable_Att3 = ""
    attributeTable_Att4 = ""

    If Me.ComboBox_equipmentBaseline.value Like "*T12*" Then
        attributeTable_Att1 = "T12_Att1_Table"
        attributeTable_Att2 = "T12_Att2_Table"
        attributeTable_Att3 = "T12_Att3_Table"
        attributeTable_Att4 = "T12_Att4_Table"

    ElseIf Me.ComboBox_equipmentBaseline.value Like "*F*T8*" Then
        attributeTable_Att1 = "T8_Att1_Table"
        attributeTable_Att2 = "T8_Att2_Table"
        attributeTable_Att3 = "T8_Att3_Table"
        attributeTable_Att4 = "T8_Att4_Table"

....
End If
    Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att1.Clear
    Me.TextBox_equipmentBaseline_Att1_entervalue = ""
    Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att1.List = Range(attributeTable_Att1).value
    If Range(attributeTable_Att1 & "[[#Headers]]") Like "*n/a*" Then
        Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att1.Caption = ""
    Else
        Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att1.Caption = Right(Range(attributeTable_Att1 & "[[#Headers]]").value, Len(Range(attributeTable_Att1 & "[[#Headers]]").value) - 7) ' & Chr(10) & "(select one)"
        Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att1.ListIndex = 0
    End If

...
    '===== Automatically select default values for specific equipment =====
    Select Case Me.ComboBox_equipmentBaseline.value
    
    Case "FLT8 - 2 Ft"
    ' Automatically select "17W" in the Lamp Wattage ListBox
    If Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att2.Caption Like "*Wattage*" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.List(i) = "17W" Then
                Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Automatically select "IS N" in the Ballast ListBox
    If Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att3.Caption Like "*Ballast*" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.List(i) = "IS N" Then
                Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
Case "FLT8 - 3 Ft"
    ' Automatically select "25W" in the Lamp Wattage ListBox
    If Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att2.Caption Like "*Wattage*" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.List(i) = "25W" Then
                Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att2.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    ' Automatically select "IS N" in the Ballast ListBox
    If Me.Label_equipmentBaseline_Att3.Caption Like "*Ballast*" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.List(i) = "IS N" Then
                Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If

...
I tried adding
Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.Value = Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.List(i) after
Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.ListIndex = i
but that didn't help.
I added the following code in responce to a recommendation last time I posted the question. The results of the test are as follows.
Found 'IS N' at listindex 2 in ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3
Value 'willNotMatch' not found in list ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3
It appears Debug.Print Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.value is printing null.
A watch on Me.ListBox_equipmentBaseline_Att3.Value = ""
Both ListBox's are single column and they are on a UserForm. Most of the code I inherited. I just added the case statement starting with Case "FLT8 - 2 Ft"
Sub Test()
SetListBox Me.ListBox1, "Val002"   'ignoring the return value in this case
Debug.Print Me.ListBox1.Value      '> Val002

'you can use the return value if the match needed to succeed
If Not SetListBox(Me.ListBox1, "willNotMatch") Then
    MsgBox "value not matched!", vbExclamation
End If
Debug.Print Me.ListBox1.Value      '> Null

End Sub
'Set the list index for listbox lo to match findValue
'  Optionally clear any existing selection if no match is found
Function SetListBox(lb As Object, findValue) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
If lb.List(i) = findValue Then
Debug.Print "Found '" & findValue & _
"' at listindex " & i & " in " & lb.Name
lb.ListIndex = i
SetListBox = True
Exit For
End If
Next i
If Not SetListBox Then Debug.Print _
"Value '" & findValue & "' not found in list " & lb.Name
'optional - deselect any existing selection if no match was made
If Not SetListBox Then lb.ListIndex = -1
End Function
